# How to find all solutions of $e^z = 2020(-1 + i)$ in rectangular coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

How do I find all solutions of $e^z = 2020(-1 + i)$ (in rectangular coordinates)?

This is what I have so far:

$e^z = e^x \cos(y) + e^x \sin(y)i$

so $e^x \cos(y) = -2020$ and $e^x \sin(y) = 2020$.

No idea how to continue from here.

Comment: then $\tan(y)=$?

Comment: -1, but dont see how I could use that to find all solutions of $e^z = 2020(-1 + i)$

Comment: Does that mean that there are 2 solutions: at $\frac{3}{4} \pi$ and $\frac{7}{4} \pi$ on the unit circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note,

$$e^z = 2020(-1 + i)=2020\sqrt2 e^{i\frac{3\pi}4+i2\pi n}$$

Then, the solutions are,

$$z=  \ln(2020\sqrt2 e^{i\frac{3\pi}4+i2\pi n}) = \ln(2020\sqrt2)+(\frac{3\pi}4+2\pi n)i$$

Comment: Is $\frac{7}{4} \pi$ not a solution as well?

Comment: @ABC - it is not. because cos(y) < 0 and sin(y)>1, y is in the second quadrant.

Comment: I think I am still not understanding it fully. Could you perhaps elaborate on how you used cos(y) and sin(y) to derive $(\frac{3\pi}4+2\pi n)i$?

Comment: @ABC - Note $-i+1 = \sqrt2 (\cos y + i\sin y)$.  $\cos y = -\frac1{\sqrt2}$, so $y$ is either in 2nd or 3rd quadrant; $\sin y = \frac1{\sqrt2}$, so $y$ is either in 1st or 2nd quadrant. Thus, y is in the 2nd quadrant.

Comment: Now I understand. So it's not necessary to look at tan(y)? But what if I wanted to, how would I approach that?

Comment: @ABC - you can calculate tan(y) = -1. but it can not uniquely determine y.